# Why is a key image xHp(P), and not something simpler like Hs(x)?

Tags: ringct, key-image

I understand how ringCTs work and know that they require a key image of the private key of the input that is actually being spent. How is this created? Couldn’t you just hash the private key of the real input?

Comment: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2890/7493 covers both of your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An output has public key `P` and private key `x`, where `P = xG` and `G` is the well-known ed25519 base point.

The key image is `I=x*Hp(P)` where `Hp()` is a function that takes a hash of `P` and returns a valid curve point.

> Couldn’t you just hash the private key of the real input?

Take a look at the section **3.4 Back’s Linkable Spontaneous Anonymous Group (bLSAG)
signatures** in [Zero-to-Monero](https://web.getmonero.org/library/Zero-to-Monero-2-0-0.pdf)

That is the simplest example of a linkable ring signature, and all of Monero's more complex ring signatures are essentially based on this concept.

For the key image to be verified, even the simple bLSAG scheme requires the key image to be the scalar multiplication of the private key `x` on a point other than `G`. In simple (non-Monero) situations, that alternate point could be e.g. another universally well-known point `H`. However, if Monero used `H` instead of `Hp(P)`, it would be possible for someone that sends you outputs to detect if you've later spent more than one of them (see **Notes on the hash function Hp** on page 17 of the [CryptoNote white paper](https://cryptonote.org/whitepaper.pdf)).